# Core Dump analysis with GDB - i2c library debugging

Tags: c++, gdb

I have run `mos debug-core-dump` on my local machine to debug some code running on an ESP32 with Mongoose OS. This is part of the GDB output, possible to get some help interpreting it?

```
Dump contains FreeRTOS task info
Loaded core dump from last snippet in  /core
0x40186bb9 in TwoWire::read (this=0x3ffb6d98 <Wire>)
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/deps/arduino-wire/src/mgos_arduino_wire.cpp:133
133       return (pbyte_to_recv < recv_buf + n_bytes_avail) ? *pbyte_to_recv++ : -1;
#0  0x40186bb9 in TwoWire::read (this=0x3ffb6d98 <Wire>)
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/deps/arduino-wire/src/mgos_arduino_wire---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
.cpp:133
#1  0x400d72db in ACS71020::getRaw (this=0x3ffb4b14 <mySensor>, 
    reg_address=48 '0')
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/src/ACS71020.cpp:115
#2  0x400d7496 in ACS71020::custom_en (this=0x3ffb4b14 <mySensor>)
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/src/ACS71020.cpp:425
#3  0x400d9131 in mgos_app_init ()
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/src/main.cpp:476
#4  0x400d3466 in mgos_init () at /mongoose-os/src/mgos_init.c:29
#5  0x400db5ba in mgos_init2 ()
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/deps/freertos/src/mgos_freertos.c:169
#6  0x4008279b in mgos_task (arg=0x0)
    at /home/harry/MOS/VersionJ_Mongoose/deps/freertos/src/mgos_freertos.c:180
```

here are a couple code snippets referenced (images to show line numbers):
[image: ACS71020.cpp snippet]

[image: ACS71020.cpp snippet]

Comment: Please do not show pictures of code. Instead include code as formatted text.

Comment: only showing pictures to reference code line numbers

Comment: The outputs of `p $_siginfo` and `bt -full` would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried those commands. (gdb) p $_siginfo ->$1 = void. (gdb) bt -full -> No symbol "full" in current context.